# Append an xml document to an xml node in C#?

Tags: c#, xml

How can I append an XML document to an xml node in c#?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

An `XmlDocument` *is* basically an `XmlNode`, so you can append it just like you would do for any other `XmlNode`. However, the difference arises from the fact that *this* `XmlNode` does not belong to the target document, therefore you will need to use the ImportNode method *and then* perform the append.

```
// xImportDoc is the XmlDocument to be imported.
// xTargetNode is the XmlNode into which the import is to be done.

XmlNode xChildNode = xSrcNode.ImportNode(xImportDoc, true);
xTargetNode.AppendChild(xChildNode);
```

Comment: ah yes, but what's xSrcNode?

Why do I get the error message: Cannot import nodes of type 'Document'.

What type is xTargetNode?

Comment: @fijiaaron You need to select the root element from the doc: `XmlNode xChildNode = xSrcNode.ImportNode(xImportDoc.DocumentElement, true);`

Comment: If your XmlDoc is currently typed as an XmlNode, or if you're trying to import an XmlNode you can instead do `XmlNode xChildNode = xSrcNode.ImportNode(xImportDoc.OwnerDocument.DocumentElement, true);`

Answer (score 6):

Yes:

```
XmlNode imported = targetNode.OwnerDocument.ImportNode(otherDocument.DocumentElement, true);
targetNode.AppendChild(imported);
```

I think this creates a clone of your document though.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps like this:

```
XmlNode node = ......  // belongs to targetDoc (XmlDocument)

node.AppendChild(targetDoc.ImportNode(xmlDoc.DocumentElement));
```

Marc

Comment: AFAIK, you are required to **import* a node if it doesn't belong to the current XmlDocument before you can append it. See my answer.

Comment: Yes, seems you need to call ImportNode indeed, but that *will* create a copy of the Xml document.....

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have the following construction:

The following structure is stored in an XmlElement named xmlElement:

```
</root>
```

and the following structure is stored in an XmlNode object named FooNode;

```
<foo>
    <bar>This is a test</bar>
    <baz>And this is another test</baz>
</foo>
```

Then you do the following:

```
XmlNode node = doc.ImportNode(FooNode.SelectSingleNode("foo"), true);
xmlElement.AppendChild(node);
```

Hope it helps someone

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the root node of the XML document in question you can append it as a child node of the node in question. Does that make sense?